# Rails form option list how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this hash constant:

```
 EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS = {
   'Please, select' => '',
   '10-50' => '10-50',
   '51-100' => '51-100',
   '101-500' => '101-500',
   '501-1999' => '501-1999',
   '+2000' => '2000',
```

}

which I want to use in Rails form as options exactly in the order it is written. Using

```
<%= pf.select(:employee_num, GroupProfile::EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS.sort)%>
```

does not give the expected result.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `sort` on the Hash, you will effectively convert the Hash to an array of key/value arrays and then sort those using `Array#<=>` which will wreck your order. Whatever you hand to `pf.select` should end up going through [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select):

> Accepts a container (hash, array, enumerable, your type) and returns a string of option tags. Given a container where the elements respond to first and last (such as a two-element array), the “lasts” serve as option values and the “firsts” as option text. **Hashes are turned into this form automatically, so the keys become “firsts” and values become lasts.**

Emphasis mine. So you should be able to say this if you're using Ruby 1.9:

```
<%= pf.select(:employee_num, GroupProfile::EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS) %>
```

If you're in 1.8 then you can change `EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS` to an array-of-arrays:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS = [
   [ 'Please, select', '' ],
   [ '10-50','10-50' ],
   [ '51-100', '51-100' ],
   [ '101-500', '101-500' ],
   [ '501-1999', '501-1999' ],
   [ '+2000', '2000' ]
]
```

to get the order right and hand that to `pf.select`. If you also need a Hash form then:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS_HASH = Hash[EMPLOYEE_NUM_OPTIONS]
```

should do the trick.

Again, if you're using 1.9 then you'll have ordered Hashes already so you don't need all this extra work.

Comment: Thank you. now i understand what is under the hood here and sure to be no confused in the future. cheers! I am using ruby 1.8 and array-of-arrays tricked made it.